# How to output an R lm() object into a SQL database?

Tags: sql-server, r, data-transfer-objects

I've been tinkering with running R commands on a SQL server by calling a procedure which runs an OLS regression using the R lm() function on a few made-up data pts in the SQL database "my_schema.data", and then outputs the object as a SQL database.

My strategy is to first create an empty SQL database named "my_schema.ols_model_db" which will then be populated with the values in the ols_model object which has been transformed into a data.frame class.

I'm almost there, but can't quite figure out how to convert the ols_model object into an R data.frame, nor do I know what the column headers will be (which we need to know in advance in order to populate the empty SQL database my_schema.ols_model_db).

Which code should be inserted into "???" in the program below?

```
my_schema.data
y x
1 5
2 9
3 17
4 26

CREATE COLUMN TABLE "my_schema"."my_schema.ols_model_db"(???);        
CREATE PROCEDURE my_schema.proc_Rcode( IN train my_schema.data, OUT ols_model_db my_schema.ols_model_db )
LANGUAGE RLANG AS BEGIN
           ols_model <- lm(y ~ x, data=train)
           ols_model_db <- data.frame(g=I(lapply(ols_model, function(x) {serialize(x, NULL)})))
           ???
END
CALL my_schema.proc_Rcode( my_schema.data my_schema.ols_model_db )
```

Comment: Is your intention to store the model object so that it can be reconstituted after extracting it?  Or do you only want to store the model summary?

Comment: @Benjamin - Both would be ideal - I'd like a model summary as well as a means of using the object to score future observations.

Comment: You should be able to push the summary easily enough using the output from the `broom` package.  The model summary is a little more tricky, but I think your best bet would be to convert the model object into a byte string and store it in a BLOB in the database.

Comment: @Benjamin - Thanks, I haven't heard of either the broom package or BLOBs so will have to look those up.

Comment: BLOBs are an SQL thing.  I've not pushed anything to a BLOB before, but I've had some fun experiences pulling them out.  Here's everything I know about working with BLOBs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569983/reconstitute-png-file-stored-as-raw-in-sql-database