# Loading jpg from SQL filestream to R image object

Tags: r, t-sql, jpeg

I'm testing different methods of loading (jpg) images into R for further processing. I have nearly 100k images and I'm happy with the processing time (doing it in 20k image per batch) but loading them takes ages.
I've tested , ,  for loading them directly from the image files but was wondering whether it could be faster reading them from SQL.

So I created a simple loader of jpg files from a directory to an (MS) SQL Filestream table + I use  to read it back to R.

All good so far but I could not figure it out how to turn the binary jpg data to any image format that I could eventually convert to df/array.

I tried:

```
# jpeg gives an error
require(jpeg)
imgname <- queryResults[1,2]
imgraw <- queryResults[1,3]
img <- readJPEG(imgraw)

# readBin wants to read from a 'connection'
binary <- readBin("imgraw", what="raw", n=1e6)
```

Is there a way of make it work with these? Or is there some sort of 'binaryTOjpg' function?

### See the base SQL and R scripts I used below

Files from a folder to SQL:

```
/* Create Filestream DB */
CREATE DATABASE LOADIMG_FSTREAM
ON
PRIMARY (
      NAME = ImgStoreDB,
      FILENAME = 'D:\SQLDATA\LOADIMG_FSTREAM.mdf'
), FILEGROUP ImgStoreFS CONTAINS FILESTREAM(
      NAME = ImgStoreFS,
    FILENAME = 'D:\SQLDATA\FileStreamIMG')
LOG ON (                        
      NAME = ImgStoreLOG,
    FILENAME = 'D:\SQLDATA\LOADIMG_FSTREAM.ldf')
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Imgs](
   [ImgID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   --[ImgNumber] VARCHAR(20),
   [ImgName] VARCHAR(50),
   [ImgImage] VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM NULL
)


DROP TABLE ##files
declare @files table (ID int IDENTITY, FileName varchar(100))
insert into @files execute xp_cmdshell 'dir "D:\DATA\train\*.jpg" /b'

select ID, FileName, CONCAT('D:\DATA\train\' , FileName) as PathAndFileName 
    INTO ##files FROM @files WHERE FileName is not NULL AND ID < 100

-- select * from ##files

-- Declare a variables 
DECLARE @img AS VARBINARY(MAX)
DECLARE @ID [int]
DECLARE @FileName [varchar](1024) 
DECLARE @PathAndFileName [varchar](1024) 
DECLARE @SelectString varchar(3000)

-- loop over first 1000 images
DECLARE ImgList_Cursor CURSOR FOR  
select ID, FileName,PathAndFileName from ##files  WHERE FileName is not NULL AND ID < 1000
OPEN ImgList_Cursor;  
FETCH NEXT FROM ImgList_Cursor INTO @ID, @FileName, @PathAndFileName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
   BEGIN  
      FETCH NEXT FROM ImgList_Cursor INTO @ID, @FileName, @PathAndFileName
    -- Load the image data
        DECLARE @sql_string nvarchar(max) = 
            N'INSERT INTO Imgs (ImgID, ImgName, ImgImage) SELECT NEWID(), ''' + @FileName 
                + ''', (SELECT CAST(bulkcolumn AS VARBINARY(MAX)) as img FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ' 
                + quotename(@PathAndFileName,nchar(39)) + ', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x) as myjpg '

        select @sql_string 
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql_string --, N'@PrimaryKey int',  @PrimaryKey
   END;  
CLOSE ImgList_Cursor;  
DEALLOCATE ImgList_Cursor;  
DROP TABLE ##files
GO  

/*
-- Check images w SQL
select * from Imgs
*/
```

From SQL to R:

```
require(RJDBC)
# connect
drv <- JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
            , "D:\\install\\RJDBC\\sqljdbc_6.0\\enu\\sqljdbc4.jar")
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:sqlserver://mysqlserver", "uesraaaa", "pwaaaaaaaaa")
#then build a query and run it
sqlText <- paste("
   select * from LOADIMG_FSTREAM.dbo.Imgs
  ", sep="")
queryResults <- dbGetQuery(conn, sqlText)
class(queryResults)
dim(queryResults)
head(queryResults,1)
# bye
dbDisconnect(conn)
```

Platform basics:
- SQL 2014 R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
- Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
- Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
- Freshly downloaded JDBC from MS

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but here is the approach I had to take with RODBC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569983/reconstitute-png-file-stored-as-raw-in-sql-database

Comment: Thanks heaps @Benjamin ! There seem to be the same core of the problem. I'll post the adapted code asap. (ATM I have a 4kb jpg as an output of the 135kb image..)