# Data from ODBC blob not matching return from SQL query

Tags: r, rodbc

I’m reading a BLOB field from an ODBC data connection (the BLOB field is a file). I connect and query the database, returning the blob and the filename. The blob itself does not contain the same data as I find in the database however. My code is as follows along with the data returned vs in the DB.

```
library(RODBC)

sqlret<-odbcConnect('ODBCConnection')
qry<-'select content,Filename from document with(nolock) where documentid = \'xxxx\'' 
df<-sqlQuery(sqlret,qry)
close(sqlret)

rootpath<-paste0(getwd(),'/DocTest/')

dir.create(rootpath,showWarnings = FALSE)

content<-unlist(df$content)
fileout<-file(paste0(rootpath,df$Filename),"w+b")
writeBin(content, fileout)
close(fileout)
```

database blob is

```
0x50726F642050434E203A0D0A35363937313533320D0A33383335323133320D0A42463643453335380D0A0D0A574C4944203A0D0A0D0…
```

the dataframe’s content is

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004b020000000000000d0000f1000000008807840200000000d0f60c0c0000…
```

The filenames match up, as does the size of the content/blob.

Comment: The problem is that RODBC doesn't correctly bind most data types. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76862192/why-does-r-crash-when-retreiving-data-from-rodbc/76870719#76870719

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exact approach you take may vary depending on your ODBC driver.  I'll demonstrate how I do this on MS SQL Server, and hopefully you can adapt it to your needs.

I'm going to use a table in my database called `InsertFile` with the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InsertFile](
  [OID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [filename] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [filedata] [varbinary](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Now let's create a file that we will push into the database.

```
file <- "hello_world.txt"
write("Hello world", file)
```

I need to do a little work to prep the byte code for this file to go into SQL.  I use this function for that.

```
prep_file_for_sql <- function(filename){
  bytes <- 
    mapply(FUN = readBin,
           con = filename,
           what = "raw",
           n = file.info(filename)[["size"]],
           SIMPLIFY = FALSE) 
  chars <- 
    lapply(X = bytes,
           FUN = as.character)
  vapply(X = bytes,
         FUN = paste,
         collapse = "",
         FUN.VALUE = character(1))

}
```

Now, this is a bit strange, but the `SQL Server` ODBC driver is pretty good at writing `VARBINARY` columns, but terrible at reading them.

Coincidentally, the `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` ODBC driver is terrible at writing `VARBINARY` columns, but okay-ish with reading them.

So I'm going to have two RODBC objects, `conn_write` and `conn_read`.

```
conn_write <- 
  RODBC::odbcDriverConnect(
    paste0("driver=SQL Server; server=[server_name]; database=[database_name];",
           "uid=[user_name]; pwd=[password]")
  )

conn_read <- 
  RODBC::odbcDriverConnect(
    paste0("driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0; server=[server_name]; database=[database_name];",
           "uid=[user_name]; pwd=[password]")
  )
```

Now I'm going to insert the text file into the database using a parameterized query.

```
sqlExecute(
  channel = conn_write,
  query = "INSERT INTO dbo.InsertFile (filename, filedata) VALUES (?, ?)",
  data = list(file,
              prep_file_for_sql(file)),
  fetch = FALSE
)
```

And now to read it back out using a parameterized query.  The unpleasant trick to use here is recasting your `VARBINARY` property as a `VARBINARY` (don't ask me why, but it works).

```
X <- sqlExecute(
  channel = conn_read,
  query = paste0("SELECT OID, filename, ",
                 "CAST(filedata AS VARBINARY(8000)) AS filedata ",
                 "FROM dbo.InsertFile WHERE filename = ?"),
  data = list("hello_world.txt"),
  fetch = TRUE,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Now you can look at the contents with

```
unlist(X$filedata)
```

And write the file with

```
writeBin(unlist(X$filedata),
         con = "hello_world2.txt")
```

#### BIG DANGEROUS CAVEAT

You need to be aware of the size of your files.  I usually store files as a `VARBINARY(MAX)`, and SQL Server isn't very friendly about exporting those through ODBC (I'm not sure about other SQL Engines; see [RODBC sqlQuery() returns varchar(255) when it should return varchar(MAX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366195/rodbc-sqlquery-returns-varchar255-when-it-should-return-varcharmax?answertab=votes#tab-top) for more details)

The only way I've found to get around this is to recast the `VARBINARY(MAX)` as a `VARBINARY(8000)`.  That obviously is a terrible solution if you have more than 8000 bytes in your file.  When I need to get around this, I've had to loop over the `VARBINARY(MAX)` column and created multiple new columns each of length 8000, and then paste them all together in R. (check out: [Reconstitute PNG file stored as RAW in SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569983/reconstitute-png-file-stored-as-raw-in-sql-database))

As of yet, I've not come up with a generalized solution to this problem.  Perhaps that's something I should spend more time on, though.

Comment: This is magic, thanks so much for the answer. Is RODBC the only package that has the 8000 limit or do all of the sql packages?

Comment: I don't think there's a clear answer to that. I believe a part of the problem is that `VARCHAR(MAX)` and `VARBINARY(MAX)` variables in some ODBC drivers report a length of `0`, so `RODBC` can't know what to do about allocating space.  So while there may be some limitations related to `RODBC`, there are also limitations in the ODBC driver provided by the flavor of SQL you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The limit of the 8000 is imposed by the ODBC driver and not by the RODBC, DBI or odbc packages.

Use the latest driver to remove the limitation:  ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

There is no need to convert column to VARBINARY with this latest driver.

Following should work

```
X <- sqlExecute(
  channel = conn_read,
  query = paste0("SELECT OID, filename, ",
                 "filedata ",
                 "FROM dbo.InsertFile WHERE filename = ?"),
  data = list("hello_world.txt"),
  fetch = TRUE,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```