# using RODBC sqlquery in R to import long string, but R truncate the string, how to get around this?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, truncate, rodbc

I'm using R library(RODBC) to import the results of a sql store procedure and save it in a data frame then export that data frame using write.table to write it to xml file (the results from sql is an xml output)
anyhow, R is truncating the string (imported xml results from sql).
I've tried to find a function or an option to expand the size/length of the R dataframe cell but didn't find any
I also tried to use the sqlquery in the write.table statement to ignore using a dataframe but also it didn't work, the imported data from sql is always truncated.
Anyone have any suggestions or an answer that could help me.
here is my code

```
#library & starting the sql connection
library(RODBC)
my_conn<-odbcDriverConnect('Driver={SQL Server};server=sql2014;database=my_conn;trusted_connection=TRUE') 

#Create a folder and a path to save my output
x <- "C:/Users/ATM1/Documents/R/CSV/test"
dir.create(x, showWarnings=FALSE)
setwd(x)
Mpath <- getwd()

#importing the data from sql store procedure output
xmlcode1 <- sqlquery(my_conn, "exec dbo.p_webDefCreate 'SA25'", stringsAsFactors=F, as.is=TRUE)


#writing to a file
write.table(xmlcode1, file=paste0(Mpath,"/SA5b_def.xml"), quote = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

what I get is plain text that is not the full output.
and the code below is how I find the current length of my string

> stri_length(xmlcode1)
>   [1] 65534

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RODBC and Microsoft SQL Server: Truncating Long Character Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249788/rodbc-and-microsoft-sql-server-truncating-long-character-strings)

Comment: Hi Benjamin, that question does not answer mine, my store procedure results is xml not a table that I can try and play with it's column sizes or whatever. that xml output is being read as a string and then saved to an xml file where it's supposed to be viewed as xml but it won't happen because its truncated. when I run the store procedure with a different tablename that has short result, everything runs smooth but not with the long result

Comment: You're right.  I hadn't realized that you weren't pulling the data out of a table.  I'm afraid I don't have a good solution for you.  Maybe try the `DBI` style interface? (I'm not sure how much good it will do, based on ODBC driver limitations)

Comment: unfortunately for me I can't use BDI, I'm only limited to what my agency has in term of R packages, we are not allowed to download any and they have some kind of procedure they go through before downloading any package.
Do you know of a way where I can split the imported string in a half and save it in two dataframes because I can combine those two when I write to file

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with our project, the data that was coming from the db was getting truncated to 257 characters, and I could not really get around it. Eventually I converted the column def on the db table from varchar(max) to varchar(8000) and I got all the characters back. I did not mind changing the table defintion.

In your case you can perhaps convert the column type in your proc output to varchar with some defined value if possible.

M

Answer (score 0):

I am using PostgeSQL but experienced the same issue of truncation upon importing into R with RODBC package. I used Michael Kassa's solution with a slight change to set the data type to `text` which can store a string with unlimited length per [postgresqltutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-char-varchar-text/). This worked for me.

> The `TEXT` data type can store a string with unlimited length.

`varchar()` also worked for me

> If you do not specify the n integer for the `VARCHAR` data type, it behaves like the `TEXT` datatype. The performance of the `VARCHAR` (without the size n) and `TEXT` are the same.