# dbGetQuery causes strings to be truncated to a shorter length in R

Tags: r, string, odbc

I use the ODBC package to connect to a Sybase IQ database. There are location names in one column as a varchar and when I use the command `dbGetQuery(con, statement)`, I only get the names as partial results i.e. "Manhattan, New York" becomes "Manhattan, New Yo". How to solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RODBC string getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623460/rodbc-string-getting-truncated)

Comment: no, because I have a JDBC connection and I can't change those values in windows in such a manner (PS: I'm sort of a noob in server stuff)

Comment: how do you define your connection?

Comment: drv <- JDBC("com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver", "*/jconn4.jar")

conn <- dbConnect(drv, URL, "user", "password")

Comment: and setting the parameter `MaxLongVarcharSize` does not work? Is not possible?

Comment: No, I've added that and made it conn <- RJDBC::dbConnect(drv, URL, "user", "password",
                         MaxLongVarcharSize=256000) but it still truncates strings in such a fashion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248727/discussion-between-minimalbob-and-mnist).